# gopacket layers TCP struct ACK vs Ack

Tags: go, tcp, ip, ipv4, gopacket

I am trying to construct TCP packets using the golang libraries gopacket and layers. In layers there is a struct aptly called [TCP](https://godoc.org/github.com/packetb-old/gopacket/layers#TCP). There are two ACK fields and I am unsure why there is such a distinction. One is a bool and one is a uint16. What is the purpose for this divergence. Any help is much appreciated.

```
type TCP struct {
    BaseLayer
    SrcPort, DstPort                           TCPPort
    Seq                                        uint32
    Ack                                        uint32
    DataOffset                                 uint8
    FIN, SYN, RST, PSH, ACK, URG, ECE, CWR, NS bool
    Window                                     uint16
    Checksum                                   uint16
    Urgent                                     uint16

    Options []TCPOption
    Padding []byte
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
```

Comment: One is the Acknowledgment number and the other is the ACK flag (http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/7/understanding-tcp-sequence-acknowledgment-numbers/)